# Quando carrego a classe na view, dá erro de NullException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Esse é o erro que tá dando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a linha do erro no meu cshtml

```
@( new HtmlString((SessaoUtil.Recuperar("TagGoogle") != null ? SessaoUtil.Recuperar("TagGoogle").ToString() : "")))
```

Esse é meu using no  meu cshtml

```
@model AgaxTurSiteOficial.Entities.PackageSearchInfo
```

Essa é a minha classe PackageSearchInfo

```
public class PackageSearchInfo
    {
        public int chkpacotesroteiros { get; set; }
        public int chkaereo { get; set; }
        public int chkhotel { get; set; }
        public int chkaluguelcarro { get; set; }
        public int chkcruzeiros { get; set; }
        public int chkingressos { get; set; }
        public int chkseguro { get; set; }


        public string txtDestino { get; set; }
        public string txtOrigem { get; set; }
        public string mesViagem { get; set; }
        public string datIda { get; set; }
        public string datVolta { get; set; }
        public int intAdultos { get; set; }
        public int intCriancas { get; set; }
        public int quaAdulto { get; set; }
        public int quaCrianca { get; set; }
        public int quaMaisCinco { get; set; }
        public int idGeoAreDestino { get; set; }
        public int idGeoAreOrigem { get; set; }
        public string idPacotes { get; set; }
        public string SubMit { get; set; }


        public string localPagina { get; set; }
        public string[] passos { get; set; }

    }
```

Sinceramente, tenho outro cshtml, com a mesma informação que funciona. Esse procedimento é padrão para todas as páginas nossa. Estou averiguando as outras páginas, para saber onde está diferente, mas não encontro nada. É claro que falta alguma coisa, mas não sei o que é. Postei tudo para tentar ajudar aos colegas, dando o máximo de informação, porque ajudar a distância eu sei que é osso. Se faltar mais alguma informação relevante, é só pedir que eu edito o posto e envio.

Desculpem-me pela informação errada. A linha do erro no meu CSHTML é essa.em cima do Model.chkpacotesroteiros != 0:

```
@{
     if (Model.chkpacotesroteiros != 0)
    {
         @Model.mesViagem
    }
     else
    {
         @Model.datIda @:<br />a @Model.datVolta
    }

}
```

Comment: O erro não está em nenhum trecho de código dos que você postou. Sugestão: o *debugger* é seu amigo. Aparentemente você já está a depurar o código. Veja em qual linha o programa para. Exceções do tipo `NullReferenceException` ocorrem quando você tenta realizar uma operação sobre uma variável nula. E só verificar suas variáveis uma por uma na linha onde o erro acontece.

Comment: Essa é a linha do erro. Foi mal escrita por mim.@( new HtmlString((SessaoUtil.Recuperar("TagGoogle") != null ? SessaoUtil.Recuperar("TagGoogle").ToString() : "")))

Comment: `SessaoUtil` é estático?

Comment: Retiro o que eu disse sobre o erro não estar nos códigos postados. O que o Cigano disse faz todo o sentido.

Comment: Sua dúvida é autêntica @pnet, entretanto, não sei se essa questão será realmente útil para outros usuários no futuro... pois parece que foi uma mera falta de atenção. Se for esse o caso, eu a excluiria.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, sei que é difícil para qualquer pessoa conseguir resolver problemas à distância. E às vezes temos dificuldades de dar a informação mais precisa. Muitas vezes postamos onde o problema estoura, mas muitas vezes não onde inicia. Coloquei algumas coisas para que os colegas analisassem e pudessem me ajudar na solução, mas eu não fui feliz em postar todo o código, pois como esse forum agente não pode estar postando muita coisa, eu preferir tentar ser enxuto, mas realmente postei partes que não era o problema. Estourava ali, mas não era ali a questão. Na minha Action, eu tenho o objeto SourcePackageInfo e atribui a variavel package a esse objeto. No return da Action, deverioa estar assim: return View(package); e estava assim: return View(); Ai estava a questão. O objeto não estava sendo passado para a View e por isso dava erro de NullException. Não foi proposital, pois sinceramente, se eu soubesse, não teria feito o post. Para nós, que estamos com o problema, até formular a pergunta nem sempre é fácil. Conto com a compreensão de todos, pos meu objetivo aqui é ajudar o forum a se desenvolver mais e mais. Mas agradeço a todos que tentaram me ajudar e até me ajudaram e muito. Vou marcar a resposta do Renan, mas o Cigano também merece ter a sua resposta marcada. Não sei se consigo marcar duas, acho que não. Até +++.